# creating elastic search query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elastic4s

I have this json doc in my elasticsearch:

```
{
  "personId": "5b564b6a0c000b622a55",
  "name": "Jake Harper",
  "country": "US",
  "socialSecurityNumber": 7634904,
  "personAddress": {
    "city": "Los Angeles",
    "street": "Sunset BLVD",
    "streetNumber": 149,
  },
  "additionalAddresses": [
    {
      "addressType": "office",
      "additionalAddress": {
        "city": "Santa Monica",
        "street": "3rd street",
        "streetNumber": 13
      }
    },
    {
      "addressType": "property",
      "additionalAddress": {
        "city": "mxkwUcc branch city",
        "street": "mxkwUcc BLVD",
        "streetNumber": 255
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and I want to create an elastic query that will help me to find people by:

```
personId
socialSecurityNumber
personAddress(all fields)
additionalAddresses(all fields in th array docs)
```

and im having trouble with creating the query specially with `personAddress` and `additionalAddresses`...
can anyone give me some kind of direction here..? thanks!

currently my query looks like :

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "personId": "5b564b6a0c000b622a"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "name": "Harper"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

im using multiple query cause I will get a term input and I want to check if its part of any of the above fields.

my mappings:

```
{
  "peopledb": {
    "mappings": {
      "person": {
        "properties": {
          "additionalAddresses": {
            "properties": {
              "additionalAddress": {
                "properties": {
                  "city": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "street": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "streetNumber": {
                    "type": "long"
                  },
                  "zipCode": {
                    "type": "long"
                  }
                }
              },
              "addressType": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "country": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "personAddress": {
            "properties": {
              "city": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "street": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "streetNumber": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "zipCode": {
                "type": "long"
              }
            }
          },
          "personId": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show where you're currently at with your query?

Comment: @Val sure, done :) edited the question

Comment: Have you tried to add more should constraints?

Comment: @Val but personAddress is a complex object and additionalAddresses is array of complex object...isn't there a different way to write it?

Comment: What do you want to query from these objects?

Comment: @Val so now I saw i can do ```personAddress.city: "Los"```, so just the array search left the problem

Comment: Do you need to search multiple fields from that array or only a single one?

Comment: @Val multiple, all the field in the address object: ```city, street, streetNumber```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to make `additionalAddresses` of type nested, but first let's see if [`multi_match`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) gets you a bit further:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "personId": "5b564b6a0c000b622a"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "name": "Harper"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "personAddress.city": "Los"
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "fields": ["additionalAddresses.additionalAddress.city", "additionalAddresses.additionalAddress.street", "additionalAddresses.additionalAddress.streetNumber"],
            "query": "123 Main Street"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: its not working, i could use the multi_match individually. maybe you cannot combine them? also, I was expecting that "Harp" will give me the doc with "Harper"...why it is not right now? I have to write Harper to get the docs that contains Harper in their name, i want to be able to get them if the term only Harp...

Comment: To match on prefixes, you need to use the `prefix` query instead of `match`

Comment: Can you share your mapping?

Comment: sure, updated the question and added mappings. can you maybe edit the query to use prefix? basically I want something pretty simple: I will receive a term from a client side, and they might send partial term, and I want to look for the docs that contain this term (or partial term) in the fields personId, name, personAddress (all fields), additionalAddresses (all fields). thats all

Comment: simply replace `match` by `prefix`

Comment: yes thank you Val :) now I don't understand how to use two different data types fields :/ one of my field is long and the other text, if I search "34" no problem, elastic knows how to change it to numeric, but if my input is "john" the numeric type is freaking out in the match...